# Using structures in a linked list

Tags: c

I am trying to create an append_node method to add a node to a linked list I created.
My Node structure is defined below:

```
typedef struct Node{
    struct Node next = NULL;
    int id;
} Node;
```

However, when compiling with the method below, I get the following error:
'Node' has no member named 'id'
'Node' has no member named 'next'

```
void append_node(Node *sent,int val){   
    Node *other_node = (struct Node *)malloc(1*sizeof(struct Node));
    other_node->id = val;
    Node n = *sent;
    while (n.next != NULL){
        n = n.next;
    }
    n.next = other_node;
}
```

Why is this error occurring?

EDIT:

I also have the following error

```
error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token
```

on the first line of the Node definition

Comment: A `struct` can not hold an instance of the same type as itself.

Comment: You probably meant: `struct Node *next = NULL;` (i.e. missing `*`).

Comment: the temporary `n` should be a pointer

Comment: dont think c can have default values in structs. atleast not c99

Comment: Your code is mixing typedef references with (the prefered method) struct references.  Use one of the other, but not both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are numerous errors in your code. 
here is a correct version

```
typedef struct NodeTag
{
    struct NodeTag* next;
    int id;
} Node;

void append_node(Node* sent,int val)
{   
    Node* other_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node));
    other_node->id = val;
    other_node->next = 0;
    Node* n = sent;
    while (n->next != 0)
    {
        n = n->next;
    }
    n->next = other_node;
}
```

Comment: I tried with this method, but when I call 'Node lr;' 
'lr.number = 0;'
'add_node(&lr,2);'I get a seg fault. Any idea what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You can't have Node defined again inside the same structure. This will be infinite recursion.

you can have a Pointer to the same type.

```
typedef struct Node{
    struct Node *next;
```

Comment: does the implementation see the Node definition? is some other header also defining Node?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean (new to c). I defined the struct just before the main function

Comment: @teaLeef, can you copy the code over to ideone to see it fully

Comment: Actually, it turns out the problem was that  c99 can't have default values in structs. Thanks for your help